# Student and grades arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

I have created two arrays. One String with student names and one Integer with their grades. Data is inserted by JOptionPane. Now how to show the names of students who have got a bigger grade than c??

Comment: You should probably consider creating a class Student that has two variables: name and grade. That will make manipulating the students easier because you will have to deal with only one list.

Comment: first try something and then come to stackoverflow with problem. This is your homework.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could simply iterate over your grade array and check the condition:

```
for (int i=0; i<grades.length; i++)
{
    if(grades[i] > "C") //insert your function here
}
```

However if those two parameters are closely related, they should be wrapped into a Student object.

Answer (score 0):

```
       int key=9;
       int a = 0;

       boolean found = false;   

       for ( a = 0; a < grades.length; a++)
       {
       if (grades[ a ]  == key );
       {
       found = true;      
       break;
       }
       }

       if (found)   
       {

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Is found " + key "in the index:" +a  );

       System.exit(0);
      }
```

### > How can i now make -a- to return the character(word) inside that string and not string position

Comment: I added an answer, but for the future: you should not ask new questions here, you should have posted it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like you said, just save the value, not the index.

```
int grade = grades[a];
```

or

```
String student = students[a];
```

Although I need to emphasize it again - it is NOT a good design. Java is an object-oriented language, and a grade should be an integral part of a student. This implementation is confusing, it should be remade in the following way - you declare a new class:

```
public class Student{

    private String name;
    private int grade;

    //getters and setters to access private fields
    public String getName()
    {
         return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
         this.name = name;
    }

    public int getGrade()
    {
         return this.grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(int grade)
    {
        this.grade = grade;
    }
}
```

Then you simply declare an array of Student objects, and you can iterate over it and efficiently get or modify any Student data:

```
ArrayList <Student> students = new ArrayList <Student> ();
students.add(new Student("John", 5);
students.add(new Student("Jane", 3);
students.add(new Student("Tim", 4);
for(Student s : students)
{
    //your operations here
}
```